# UnicodeEncodeError using detached screen command during startup

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, raspberry-pi, gnu-screen

I have the following small python3 test program (called: *testing*) running under root on a Raspberry Pi printing three ascii characters (abc) and three Latin-1 source coded Swedish characters (åäö):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: Latin-1 -*-
print('abc')
print('åäö')
```

There is no problem running this in a Putty SSH terminal with remote character set = UTF-8.
Output shown on terminal as:

```
abc
åäö
```

Also no problem running a detached *screen* command from the same Putty session under root using the same python3 program:

```
screen -dm -U -L -S testing /root/testing
```

In the *screen* command log *screenlog.0* I can see that what is printed is:

```
abc     in hex: 61 62 63 
Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶  in hex: C3 A5 C3 A4 C3 B6
```

Then I try to run the same detached *screen* command during startup from a script (called: *testingscreen*) in *rc.local*:

In *rc.local* is added *'/root/testingscreen'* and that script includes the same *screen* command as above:

```
#!/bin/sh
screen -dm -U -L -S testing /root/testing
```

In this case an error occur and the following is written in *screenlog.0*:

```
abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/testing", line 4, in <module>
    print('\xe5\xe4\xf6')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Please note that I have used the -U argument to the *screen* command with the following meaning: *"Run screen in UTF-8 mode. This option tells screen that your terminal sends and understands UTF-8 encoded characters. It also sets the default encoding for new windows to 'utf8'."*

Why is the behavior different and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently rc.local runs before the locale is set.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/616808/program-in-rc-local-started-not-with-standard-localization

Another solution is to use crontab with the "@reboot" which runs the command on reboot.